# Updating dictionary in python: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, dictionary

The following code gives the error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/pset6/sentiments/analyzer.py", line 20, in __init__
    positives[h] = line.strip(' ') # store word and hash code in dictionary
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

The error is being caused by the last line in the code.

For reference, I am trying to build a hash table of words from positives and negatives which are two text files.

First I hash the word to get a hashcode, then I try to store the word in the appropriate dictionary with the hashcode as the key.

```
import nltk

class Analyzer():
    """Implements sentiment analysis."""

    # create two new dictionaries to store positive and negative words in memory
    positives = {}
    negatives = {}

    def __init__(self, positives, negatives):
        """Initialize Analyzer."""

        # open positive-words.txt and read line by line, hashing each line and storing the hash and word in the appropriate dictionary
        with open(positives, "r") as lines:
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith(';'): # ignore comments at top of text file
                    continue
                else:
                    h = hash(line.strip(' ')) # hash word using built in python hash function, removing any spaces
                    positives[h] = line.strip(' ') # store word and hash code in dictionary

        # open negative-words.txt and read line by line, hashing each line and storing the hash and word in the appropriate dictionary
        with open(negatives, "r") as lines:
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith(';'):
                    continue
                else:
                    h = hash(line.strip(' '))
                    negatives[h] = line.strip(' ')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of the dictionary? From a first glance, it appears you have the name of the file and the dictionary the same, which may be causing this bug.

Comment: Inside your `__init__()`, `positives` isn't a dictionary at all - it's a parameter to the method, which happens to be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the variable whose name is `positive` (but what follows holds for `negatives` as well. Note that in

```
# ...
positives = {}
negatives = {}

def __init__(self, positives, negatives):
    """Initialize Analyzer."""
    # ...
```

the (static) variable `positives = {}` has nothing to do with the `__init__`-local variable of the same name, i mean the one in `__init__(self, positives, ...`.

If you want to use the first one, which is outside of the scope of `__init__`, you must type `self.positives` since `positives` alone refers to the argument of the method `__init__`.

Since you do not seem to be familiar with [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), you may rename one of these variables to avoid that type of confusion (even if having the same name for those two variables ***is not the reason of your problem***, contrarily to what one can read in the comments below your question). Let's keep the dictionary with the same name, and in the contrary, let's rename the arguments of `__init__`, using a name representative what it is, i.e. a filename:

```
#...

# create two new dictionaries to store positive and negative words in memory
positives = {}
negatives = {}

def __init__(self, fname_of_pos, fname_of_neg):
    """Initialize Analyzer."""

    # open positive-words.txt and read line by line, hashing each line and storing the hash and word in the appropriate dictionary
    with open(fname_of_pos, "r") as lines:
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith(';'): # ignore comments at top of text file
                continue
            else:
                h = hash(line.strip(' ')) # hash word using built in python hash function, removing any spaces
                self.positives[h] = line.strip(' ') 
    #...
```

Do you see my point ?

---

And when you want to instantiate your class, I guess that you will do

```
>>> an_instance_of_analyser = Analyzer('positive-words.txt','negative-words.txt')
```

---

To summarize, if you got an error, it was simply because, you were trying to assign a value to the (so-renamed) variable `fname_of_pos`, which is a `'str' object`.

Comment: Still don't think I completely understand OOP but I made the suggested changes and it works! Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.